# Android studio does not see connected devices

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Windows 8.1 and Android Studio 1.0.1. I need to run my app on my Nexus 10, but android studio does not see it at all! Debugging mode on the device is on, Google USB driver is installed from SDK Manager and Windows file explorer recognizes it normally. What should I do??

Comment: are you *sure it's connected? I don't use Windows, but suspect adb works the same across the board. To guarantee that your machine actually sees it, open up a terminal window and run `>adb devices`   This should show you your connected devices (if the Nexus is the only device connected then you'll only see one device).

Comment: If you see device in my computer than problem is with driver, if not you can re-install android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have developer mode and USB debugging so here are some other things to consider that have stopped me from enumerating my devices in the past:

- Make sure that your device version falls into the expected versions for the application. A device that is API 15 might not show up as available with the following config:

  `minSdkVersion 16`
  `targetSdkVersion 17`
- restart `adb` server with:

`<sdk_location>\platform-tools\adb kill-server`

`<sdk_location>\platform-tools\adb start-server`

and try again.  The [adb server](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) is the usual suspect for me when my device doesn't show up sometimes.

Comment: Killing and starting server again helped! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

This was a dodgy cable for me. Incredibly frustrating because I tried two different ones and wasn't aware that it needed to be a phone compatible cable. I was using standard usb mini charger cables. I'm confused as to why this is an issue, as I didn't think usb mini had the same sort of licensing issues as thunderbolt protocol, but there you go....

Answer (score 0):

Double check within Developer Options, "USB Debugging is checked".  Mine was grayed out and would not allow me to check the box.  Upon switching off Developers Options on the top and turn it back on, the USB Debugging check box area was made available to modify, but only for a split second.  Upon clicking the check box thereby allowing USB Debugging, Android Studios immediately recognized my phone again.  Hope this helps....